# $H_1$ of solid torus is $\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb Z^2$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have what seems like a very silly argument, but I can't figure out what's wrong with it.

Suppose that I'm trying to calculate $H_1$ of a solid torus $X$ (a torus with its ``interior'' filled in). On the one hand, it's homotopy equivalent to a circle, so $H_1(X) \cong \mathbb Z$.

On the other hand, $H_k(X)$ is isomorphic to $H_k$ of the $(k+1)$-skeleton of $X$, and in this case (letting $k = 1$) that would just be the regular torus; but then $H_1(X) = H_1(T^2) \cong \mathbb Z^2$.

What's going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The $2$-skeleton of a filled torus is not a torus (I say "the", but there are many ways to realise a torus as a CW-complex, so "a" is more correct). You can't attach the 3-cell (the "fill") to the hollow inside of a regular torus, as that void isn't homeomorphic to an open ball.

One possible 2-skeleton of the filled torus is a hollow cylinder with top and bottom, with the top and bottom glued together. This top/bottom cell kills one of the copies of $\Bbb Z$ in the homology.

Comment: How does this gluing happen? Is a hollow torus with top and bottom identified not the canonical description of a hollow torus?

Comment: @Migillope The top and bottom of the cylinder are (filled) discs, not circles. The cylinder is a closed container, not an open pipe. After gluing, what you have is a hollow torus with one disc blocking the tube. This is necessary as the 3-cell of the filled torus needs to fill a simply-connected void, and the standard (hollow) torus has no such thing.

Comment: Thank you, that clears it up!